# how to check/test specific field in json using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

This is my rspec code:-

```
  it "which has max value" do
    get :index, Devise.token_authentication_key => @user.authentication_token, business_id: @business.id, max: '1'
    expect(request.flash[:alert]).to eq(nil)
    expect(response.body).to eq([@location].to_json(LocationFinder::API_PARAMS.merge(:root => false)))
  end
```

and testing result is-

expected: "[{\"address\":\"1120 Milky Way\",\"business_id\":1,\"city\":\"Cupertino]"

```
  got: "[{\"address\":\"1120 Milky Way\",\"business_id\":1,\"city\":\"Cupertino,\"distance\":260.33452958767384,]"
```

**Here Distance is an extra field , how can i check particular fields or if it is not possible , how to eliminate "distance" field which is not check by rspec.**

Answer (score 3):

You could check individual fields using something like:

```
# get the first entry in the JSON array
json_response = JSON.parse(response.body).first

# compare each field
expect(json_response['address']).to eq(@location.address)
expect(json_response['business_id']).to eq(@location.business_id)
expect(json_response['city']).to eq(@location.city)
```

Of course you may need to adjust the exact methods you call on `@location` depending on your implementation, but that's the gist of it.